# how to add sample excel or csv file to streamlit app?

Tags: python, streamlit

I would like to add sample files, which are going to be available to download from streamlit app (as an example of correct file).

Comment: Provide a minimum code of what you are working on and state clearly your espected output.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution:

```
with open('keywords.csv') as f:
    st.download_button('Download CSV', f, 'keywords.xlsx')
```

https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/using-streamlit/how-download-file-streamlit

Comment: yes! I added the file keywords.csv which could be downloaded as a sample file after clicking the button :)

Comment: code example: st.title("""
classification algorithm
## by given key words in the company description
""")
st.sidebar.title("sample files: ")

with open('keywords.csv') as f:
    st.sidebar.download_button('download sample keywords file', f)